# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable(line 144)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling, floating-point

this is my code:

```
    if opt == "4":
        while True:
            cart_for_remove()
            remove = input("Please key in the corresponding number of the item you want to remove:")
            if remove.isalpha()==True:
                print('Please enter a valid number!')
                break
            if count==0:
                print('Please add item to cart first!')
                break
            if int(remove)<=count:
                remove = int(remove) - 1
                price_remove = float(cart[remove][3].strip('$ '))
                total_price_final -= price_remove
                savings_remove = int(total_savings[remove][2].strip('$ '))
                total_savings-=savings_remove
                del cart[remove]
                print("Item has been successfully removed from cart!")
                break
            else:
                print('Please choose a valid option')
                break
```

everything is correct until line 143.On line 144, I tried to remove the savings from total savings if item is being removed, however, this error is showing up:

> ```
> line 144, in <module>
>     savings_remove = int(total_savings[remove][2].strip('$ '))
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.
> ```

Anyone know how to correct the code,such that this error doesnt show up?

Any help/feedback is greatly appriciated.Thanks!

Comment: post the complete error and also mention which is line 144

Comment: This is too much code to expect people to help you with. Try to [trim it down to the part that causes the problem](http://sscce.org).

Comment: this is the line causing the problem `total_savings-=savings_remove` according to your code `total_savings` is a list you can't subtract a value from a list. if you want reomve an element from list you can use `total_savings.remove(savings_remove)`

Comment: Hi, i have updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You see, at this part of the code:

```
        if int(remove)<=count:
            remove = int(remove) - 1
            price_remove = float(cart[remove][3].strip('$ '))
            total_price_final -= price_remove
            savings_remove = int(total_savings[remove][2].strip('$ '))
            total_savings-=savings_remove
            del cart[remove]
            print("Item has been successfully removed from cart!")
            break
```

`total_savings[remove]` is a float. To subscript something in python means to use square brackets to get elements from an array using the element's index.

A float is obviously not subscriptable.